# Can't build redis cache with the latest imcache release(0.1.2)

Tags: java, caching

I've specified dependency as follows but I can't build a new redis cache.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.cetsoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>imcache</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.2</version><!--Can be updated for later versions-->
</dependency>
```

My code is simply as follows but I get build failure.

```
Cache<String, User> cache = CacheBuilder.redisCache().build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although we have released version 0.1.2, we haven't completed redis cache support. So, redis cache isn't available at the moment. We're sorry for any inconvenience.
We have been implementing client. Please check out our repository to find more details. https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache/tree/master/imcache-redis/src/main/java/com/cetsoft/imcache/cache/redis

Comment: Will it be available soon?

Comment: We don't have a release date yet, changes will be announced through our github page.